# How to detect if it is ok to activate additional processing

Tags: c++, cpu-usage

Motivation  is kind of hard to explain so I'll provide an example: Assume you receive high number of samples every second and your task is to classify them.

Lets also say this: You have two classifiers: heuristicFast, and heuristicSlow. So lets say that for every sample you run heuristicFast() and then if the result is close to undecided (lets say [0.45,0.55] range for classifier where 0 is class 1 and 1 is class2) I run more precise heuristicSlow.

Now the problem is that this is real time system so I want to be sure that I don't overload the CPUs (I'm using threading) even when high perchentage of calls to heuristicFast returns results in the [0.45,0.55] range.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

My best idea is to have entrycount for the heuristicSlow and then dont enter it if the entrycount is > `number_of_cores / 2`?

```
    std::atomic<int> entrycount(0);
    //...
    if (classificationNotClear(result_heuristic_fast) && (entrycount<kMaxConcurrantCalls)) 
    {
        entrycount++;
        final_result=heuristicSlow();
        entrycount--;
    }
    else
        final_result=result_heuristic_fast;

//...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even fancier solution:

Sort your fast heuristic results by uncertainty (i.e. by `abs(result-0.5)`) and run the slow heuristic for as many cases as you've got time left.

Comment: It is not time left, it is more like my code is being called, and I dont have any info regarding the buffer size, so I need to prevent buffer overflow (because if I'm to slow samples pile up ).

Comment: Well, same basic principle: you use the current buffer size as a proxy for the amount of processing time used. I.e. when the buffer size is growing, do less slow heuristics; when shrinking, more.

Comment: btw sorting is also out of the question, because it needs to be low latency :(

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl - a requirement for low latency does not mean sorting is out of the question.   It means you need to account for the time it takes to do sorting as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are building a real-time system, you have crucial information available: The maximum allowed running times for your classification and for both heuristics.

You could simply compute the leftover time for a fully fast heuristic ( total time minus sample count times fast heuristic time ) and determine how many applications of the slow heuristic fit into this time. Write this number into a counter and decrement.

Comment: An upper bound on the run time for the fast heuristic will also need to be specified.    Otherwise, given only the "leftover time", it will not be possible to estimate how many times it can be run.    It would also be easier to estimate the "leftover time" in advance, given an upper bound on time to run the "fast heuristic".